# Re-enter US with H4 Visa

Tags: visas, usa, h1b-visas

My family and I reside in the US and we have H1/H4 visas. My family members have H4 visas.

If my family traveled outside of the US, would they be allowed to get back into the US if I wasn't with them (H1 holder)?

I intend to be in the US upon their re-entry.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can enter on their own, without you.